# How to use AVFoundation to show subtitle while showing a video?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app where I show a video, I need to show a subtitle inside the video. I couldn't find a way to do it. Is this doable using AVFoundation ? Or should I hock-up something around it.

```
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil) 
player.numberOfLoops = -1 // play indefinitely 
player.prepareToPlay() 
player.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way is create a separate subtitles layer (`CATextLayer`) and add as a sublayer to the player layer. You can set up a periodic time observer to trigger every second to update the subtitles.

You can find a sample project here [SubRipForCocoa](https://github.com/sstigler/SubRipForCocoa). Please note that, you have to write the same concept in Swift.